# Calculation of currentDelayMs in webrtc-internals

Tags: delay, webrtc

What is currentDelayMs for video stream actually ?

How currentDelayMs is calculated in webrtc-internals? Why it differs from Rtt?

I tried to get an average of delay in video and audio from the graphs. Sometimes average delay is found about 2.25s. I want to know what it represents and how it is being calculated.

Comment: Probably done directly from the RTP timestamps

Comment: After some tests, I found that the RTT is not counted in the currentDelayMs. According to the [git](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/d8a03facf6986a011c8f889c63d87f9216a1e912%5E!/) : 
_It returns the current total delay (packet buffer and sync buffer) of NetEq_

Comment: I don't know about packet and sync buffer clearly, trying to get a bigger picture. But Rtt has to differ from currentDelayMs, because i took average from graphs for audio. Rtt for sending was 1.5 when currentDelayMs for receiving was about 100. Last one is definitely in ms, but is Rtt ?
As i see, currentDelay is not as simple as single packet delay. Is there any popular thread or issue where these measurement terms are thoroughly discussed ?

Comment: I also found a correlation between the CurrentDelayMs and the JitterBufferMs (Packet or Sync buffer ?). RTT and CurrentDelayMs were for me values in milliseconds. I didn't find any popular thread neither :/